# Mapping an array of each object in array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I've got a data.json file with an array of group objects, and each group object contains products array, like:

```
[
{
 "groupId": int
 "familyId": int,
 "products": array (lenght of 10-50)
 }
{
 "groupId": int
 "familyId": int,
 "products": array (lenght of 10-50)
 }, and so on...
]
```

I would like to map them like:

```
<ul> GroupId 
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
<ul/>

<ul>
   GroupId
   <li>Product 1</li>
   <li>Product 2</li>
</ul>
etc.
```

I've tried to use foreach function and then map every array but it doesn't work.

```
import data from '../data.json';
let productsList = []; 
 
{data.forEach((el) => {productsList.push(el.products)})}
{productsList.forEach((array) => {
    array.map((el) => {
         return (
             <ul>
                  <li>{el.name}</li>
             </ul>
         )
      })
})}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] illustrating what specifically you tried and what _"doesn't work"_ means.

Comment: The post is already edited

Comment: That's half of it. Given that forEach returns undefined it's unclear why you expected it to work.

Comment: When i add console.log(array) to forEach statement i receive an actual array

Comment: You can _log_ the array, sure; I said it doesn't _return_ anything. Also note the HTML you want to emit isn't entirely valid.

Comment: Could you explain me, how it should be done then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you solve this with simple react components, it will make your code more readable.

I created a simple example to solve your issue

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      groupId: 1,
      familyId: 1,
      products: [
        { id: 1, name: "product 1", price: 10 },
        { id: 2, name: "product 2", price: 20 }
      ]
    },
    {
      groupId: 2,
      familyId: 2,
      products: [{ id: 3, name: "product 3", price: 30 }]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((group) => (
        <ProductGroup group={group} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ProductGroup Component

```
const ProductGroup = ({ group }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>{group.groupId}</ul>
      {group.products.map((product) => (
        <ProductItem product={product} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

ProductItem Component

```
const ProductItem = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <span>{product.name}</span>
      <span style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>{product.price}$</span>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, didn't event think about creating few components and passing data to them. You are genius :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const listItems = () => (
  <>
    {array.map((group) => (
      <ul key={group.groupId}>
        {group.groupId}
        {group.products.map((productList, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{productList}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    ))}
  </>
);
```